# Way to expose appstore IDs but keep them secured for release

Tags: iphone, security, app-store

I am working on an application that will allow the user to purchase content from the app store
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH1-SW1

These products require a "ProductID" that ties them to whatever is in the appstore.

I will need to store these IDs somewhere in the application so I know what to send the server when the purchase button is clicked.

I wish to expose these ID's and allow non-programmers to enter any ID they want in both our side and the server side, and not have to call on a programmer to go into the code and change some enum.

I figured a config file would not be very secure, for in the end it's just a text file that a user could potentially view after purchasing the app. May not be a huge problem if a user saw the ID, but I don't like the idea of anybody seeing the innards that go through a payment process

Assuming im making sense here, whats a good way to expose these IDs but still keep them secure so users may not find them?

Also curious, how secure is something like an enum in c++? Can people break the .exe down and see the code and its values?

Answer (score 1):

For your final question, yes and no. If they have access to the debugging information (a PDB in Microsoft land) then yes. But armed with just an exe and disassembler, you will see only the constant values that are assigned to the enum members.